# (Foundation CSS) Dropdowns are not working

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

So dropdowns aren't working when using foundation (not even the code copy-pasted from the foundation docs).

This Html is generated using Play! Framework, and I am viewing it using chrome. This code is running on Localhost, not a foreign server. (Maybe chrome is blocking js on localhost or something?)

The following is the code I'm using. Any help would be appreciated.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7CZq/

```
code
```

Comment: please paste some code you tried. if you want to show some working / not working code, i would suggest something like jsfiddle as it then can be executed, i think not all people here have time just to read some paste bin somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things that I see here that could be causing problems.

The first major issue is you are not including `foundation.topbar.js` file, which is needed to implement the dropdowns.

The other issue is you should call `$(document).foundation()` at the bottom of the page to allow foundations javascript components to manipulate the DOM of the topbar to add the proper elements and classes need for the topbar dropdowns.